# Determine lagrange multiplier LASSO

Tags: r, lasso, lagrange-multipliers

I used the function l1ce from the lasso2 package in R, since I need to solve a minimization problem with a lasso constraint.

min f(x) s.t. ||beta||

where beta are the parameters. The reason it cannot be done by glmnet/LARS is that I need to be able to supply the method with weights (not possible with LARS) & moreover, the function cannot be minimized by the gradiënt descent method of glmnet.

Unfortunately, I can only give the absolute or relative bound for the L1 norm of the regression coefficients to l1ce. But I need the value for the Lagrange multiplier lambda since I am interested in the objective function:

f(x) + lambda*norm||beta||

where lambda is the Lagrange multiplier

Can someone explain me how to go from this absolute/relative bound to lambda?

Thanks in advance